# Blackberry application - get application memory usage stats

Tags: blackberry, memory-management

I'm trying to get the memory usage statistics (RAM, Flash and object handles) specific to our application, to be displayed on the device (not through the profiler). I've been using the [Memory class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/Memory.html) to track general memory usage, but could not find a way to get the specific memory info.

Is there a way to get this information from the Blackberry? Maybe using the application's process id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another one [Runtime](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/java/lang/Runtime.html) but also gives total mem stats...

what you can do with module is get it's code size [CodeModuleManager.html#getModuleCodeSize(int)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/system/CodeModuleManager.html#getModuleCodeSize%28int%29)

another tip is to compare memory statistic on app start and after main screen will be presented

also you could measure size of each object in application [Sizeof for Java - Object sizing revisited](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-12/02-qa-1226-sizeof.html?page=1)

but all this activity itself will change performance :)

Comment: Thanks Max for the tips! I guess I'll stick to profiling and comparing general stats  :)