# how to get current cpu usage and memory usage in blackberry?

Tags: memory, blackberry, cpu-usage

I am making an application in blackberry,
  Here i want to know the  current cpu usage and memory usage. How to find that?

Comment: if this hasn't been asked before, I'd be very surprised...

Comment: Check this answer to get device memory usage, http://stackoverflow.com/a/8211152/431639. There is no API to get the CPU usage, check this http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-get-the-memoery-usage-of-an-individual-app/m-p/1543639/highlight/true#M190035. If you are interested about the memory usage for an application then check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418778/blackberry-application-get-application-memory-usage-stats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this link [Memory](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Memory.html)

```
Memory.getRAMStats().getFree();
Memory.getRAMStats().getAllocated());
```